# Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component Error while using Shell32

Tags: c#, .net

```
public static void UnZip(object param)
{
    object[] args = (object[])param;
    string zipFile = (string)args[0];
    string folderPath = (string)args[1];


    if (!File.Exists(zipFile))
        throw new FileNotFoundException();

    if (!Directory.Exists(folderPath))
    Directory.CreateDirectory(folderPath);

    Shell32.Shell objShell = new Shell32.Shell();
    Shell32.Folder destinationFolder = objShell.NameSpace(folderPath);
    Shell32.Folder sourceFile = objShell.NameSpace(zipFile);

    foreach (var file in sourceFile.Items())
    {
        destinationFolder.CopyHere(file, 4 | 16);
    }
}
```

Trying to unzip the folder and saving it on the destination Shell32.Folder sourceFile = objShell.NameSpace(zipFile); gives error . Can anyone help?

Comment: Why don'd you use build in zip methods in C#? Are you sure the last command is correct. The previous (identical commands) opens a directory but ZIP file is not a directory.

Comment: Build in zip methods gives invalid rar error for some files.

Comment: if both methods fail (as this isnt working either) ... something is fundementally wrong

Comment: That works but only on rar file format. I want something that works on all formats

Comment: You are asking for a pony, they are hard to shop for.  The author of the RAR format also created 7-zip.  He's got a .NET binding available for it.

Comment: Are you sure the files are correct ZIP format? You say "invalid rar", but as far as I know Windows do not support rar *(only zip)*. But you can install some extension that support a archive. But are you sure, that this will work on each computer? I'm sure, that this will not work on my computer *(at least not for rar files)*.

Comment: I got that!! used 7z dlls. Thanks guys :)